# C# HttpClient URI is not escaping properly

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to get my URL to escape but it's not working properly. Ironically, on my MacBook when I execute this part of code

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.example.com/?i=123%34", true);
// it returns http://www.example.com/?i=123%34 which is exactly what I want.
```

The problem is that my IDE says it's obsolete and it does not work on my Windows machine. It's the exact same project, and IDE. So I tried to find a solution, which someone suggested

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString("http://www.example.com/?i=123%34")); 
// this returns http://www.example.com/?i=123%2534 which is what I DONT want.
```

So how do I approach this issue? I looked all over the web and I can't find any solutions. I need to know how to properly escape this URL. The second method posted above does not work like the first method above.

I verified the GET requests via Fiddler, so everything is indeed happening.

Update:

Again, I need the server to receive the URL exactly how the string is declared. I want the server to handle the conversion. I cannot substitute %25 for the % symbol. It MUST be received exactly how I the string is declared. Additionally, "http://www.example.com/?i=1234" is NOT what I want either.

Comment: Is that %34 supposed to be a 4 (that's what %34 encodes to), or is it important that you get back i=123%34 (instead of i=1234)

Comment: @Kolichikov it's important that I get it as i=123%34 and no I cannot use %25 in place of the % symbol. Literally, how the string inside the URI is declared is how I need the server to receive it.

Comment: Any chance, that this issue is ODATA related? The serverside of OData also needs the exact value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the configuration of your web server on Windows, that allows double escaping. Your original URL is http://www.example.com/?i=123%34, which when unescaped, becomes http://www.example.com/?i=1234.

Your web server on Windows, on the other hand, escapes the `%` character again instead of unescaping `%34`. Thus, it turns into http://www.example.com/?i=123%2534.

This is why you should not use characters like `%` in the URL before it gets escaped.

Edit -

I typed the following two URLs in Firefox to see how the parameters are received on the server.

The value of `i` in http://www.example.com/?i=123%34 is `1234`.

The value of `i` in http://www.example.com/?i=123%2534 is `123%34`

If the server must receive the % character, it must be escaped in order for it to be dispatched over HTTP. There's literally no other way to send it over the wire. If you don't escape the `%` character, it will be treated as an escape sequence along with `34` and automatically turn into `4` on the server.

If your network inspector shows you unescaped text in the request, it's because it's prettifying the URL before displaying it to you.

Comment: I understand that, but in my case I require the % to still be in there. It's not webserver related, it's the program I am writing client side. I require the output to look exactly like this "http://www.example.com/?i=123%34" so that the remote server can handle the conversion. However, as I stated above, I do not want use %25 to substitute for the percent symbol. I literally need the string to be exactly as how declared it. No ifs and or butts. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Turn off double escaping on your web server on Windows. I think it comes under request filtering on IIS.

Comment: I am not working with a webserver. It is a program I am writing on my windows desktop.

Comment: I made an edit to my answer to explain what's going on.

Comment: I don't think you understand my issue very well. You said theres no way but I did it using the obsolete method. And I cannot use %25, the server MUST see the %34 so it can convert the URL on the server end. It MUST see %34, NOT %2534. That is not the same thing in my case.

Comment: If you re-read my question, I want to know how to PROPERLY escape it because the second method above is not working. The first method is obsolete but runs on my mac, if I try to compile the same code on my windows it treats it like %2534 because my compiler says its obsolete and will always be set to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with the string reading ht tp://www.example.com/?i=1234, you can try
`Uri url = new Uri(Uri.UnescapeDataString("http://www.example.com/?i=123%34"));`

Comment: I am not okay with the string reading like that, it needs to read exactly like "http://www.example.com/?i=123%34"

Comment: Is this on a web server? If it is, perhaps [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc3c1b8a-e70c-4595-a26e-6412d6dc3722/systemuri-class-different-escaping-behaviour-in-azure-vs-net-framework?forum=windowsazuredevelopment) might work for you.

Comment: This is not on a webserver, it is a program I am writing.